# Net Core NHibernate System.Data.SQLite could not be found

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate, .net-core

I am writing a Console App on Net Core 2.0. My App uses NHibernate Fluent to work with SQLite local db.

This is how I configure NHibernate:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        var dbConnectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TestDb.sqlite;Version=3;Password=;Foreign Keys=True;Page Size=1024";

        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(dbConnectionString)
                .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<NHibernateHelper>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                .Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    public static void CloseSession()
    {
        _sessionFactory.Close();
        _sessionFactory.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I try to build configuration I receive an exception:
[image]

I have added the following references from Nuget:

- FluentNHibernate (2.1.2)
- NHibernate (5.1.3)
- System.Data.SQLite (1.0.108)

My local DB is created using SQLite Studio and database type=System.Data.SQLite.

What I am doing wrong? Maybe I am using wrong provider?

Comment: Any reason why it's not `System.Data.SQLite.Core`? The SQLite assemblies are not being deployed to where running code is expecting to find them. Is there something in the SQLite documentation about how to manage this?

Comment: I tried it and I receive next warning: "warning NU1701: Package 'System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.108' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project"
@DavidOsborne

Comment: Ah. I think I've confused the 'Core' part with .Net Core. I don't think they're the same.

Comment: I'm not sure about the state of SQLite's support for .Net Core. Scanning the document hasn't helped. However, I've noticed that when using the `System.Data.SQLite.Core` package, the `SQLiteInterop.dll` file is deployed and the code runs. You need to find a way of getting the appropriate SQLite binary into a place where the NH code can resolve a type from it. How this is done with a .Net Core-compatible version of SQLite, I don't know right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

---

**Step 1** Use package [System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.109] in your project.

**Step 2** Download package [System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.109.1].

**Step 3** Copy [runtimes] folder which in package [System.Data.SQLite 1.0.109.1] to your project's folder with follow file mapping.

```
[package]  -->  [project folder]
runtimes/win-x86/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll  -->  runtimes/win-x86/native/SQLite.Interop.dll
runtimes/win-x64/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll  -->  runtimes/win-x64/native/SQLite.Interop.dll
runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll  -->  runtimes/linux-x64/native/SQLite.Interop.dll
runtimes/osx-x64/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll  -->  runtimes/osx-x64/native/SQLite.Interop.dll
```

Then your *.csproj file should include follow content.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="runtimes\linux-x64\native\SQLite.Interop.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="runtimes\osx-x64\native\SQLite.Interop.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="runtimes\win-x64\native\SQLite.Interop.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="runtimes\win-x86\native\nssm.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="runtimes\win-x86\native\SQLite.Interop.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Step 4** Just build and run your application.

**PS**:casue package [System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.109] is unlisted,you should use package [System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.109] by modify *.csproj file with text editor.

Comment: Do I need to set in *.csproj "copy all dependencies to output directory"?

Comment: Thank you very much! How can you make those mapping? in the *.csproj?

Comment: I tried in net core application but can't build my application:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.109" />
  </ItemGroup>
namespace System.Data.SQLite couldn't be found.
Have you tried to do it in NET CORE console app?

Comment: It's my fault.It's [System.Data.SQLite.Core] not [System.Data.SQLite].i edited my answer again.

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: I tried this out. It works on Windows, but on Linux I still get the following error:

 System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load shared library 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libSQLite.Interop.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: If you runing on Linux x64,copy a file [runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netstandard2.0/SQLite.Interop.dll] which in NuGet package to your program folder.Then run your program again,it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Jul 2020**
Just add nuget package [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core) to your project and the error will go away.